# What kind of code is in that file *.cpp.. #define mdTyVzgFy4_0UFy9GimmM

Tags: c++

I just downloaded an open source code from a library called aruco for QR code detection written in C++, and while I was examing the code I found some files that doesn't look like c++..
Would anyone understand what kind of code is that? It looks like that

```
#define  mUXyv8dbk5ppT_acPhWw1  mFzTZaNOrvPJ32i9gU3Wr9J28M8DBzQ(a,:,[,+,c,+,:,^,Z,Z,/,-,r,O,[,;,9,e,;,P)
#define  mmdgJNaGE2dbCM6TccQ56  mkzSZJDew824aa0gKauM6fZ2VRvPUyZ(^,Q,5,r,j,P,t,B,c,;,T,A,o,W,},u,*,e,7,/)
#define  mVBw_rTkATYMOTRmsNe_B  mGJoExPsp9LQpgvTNdOhH4AqaFjFPrq(+,W,4,t,i,o,d,2,e,P,1,A,:,a,E,S,v,F,Y,V)
#define  mH9xkXr1In9WhMDYLLAkQ  mhN2hPhnFFq5alNSwVOjtfx8xECWu2g(R,r,R,z,t,2,i,b,!,k,S,n,e,C,k,K,5,o,K,a)
#define  mSye5PefiM2uFq__QqZRQ  m_dk3EP_dRaChCeAYkjUT4mGB6eHLjG(s,Y,^,r,*,P,D,X,y,^,b,},k,4,a,=,i,X,!,v)
#define  mJpQJFURUc57_1UwCTPvr  mByXC_NAGVGzCcmUEv_c9mAYK8t5jBN(t,R,.,>,!,i,W,0,R,C,*,Y,A,>,K,h,T,-,*,8)
#define  my9E4sAt6II28meWefBqO  mu1aRcYPGwwmkdvLrXjWyYkshrNbQfZ(8,N,+,t,},r,I,T,=,C,*,h,!,m,{,/,D,y,_,T)
#define  mRtPBvwiZzHWglctKPmaF  msiqIfe8Aci2FIHOTIR3qsdKyqc9jUO(7,i,j,^,_,^,6,},I,<,E,-,/,d,j,=,:,N,+,s)
#endif

#ifndef _ARUCO_MarkerDetector_Impl_H
#define _ARUCO_MarkerDetector_Impl_H
#include "aruco_export.h"
#include "markerdetector.h"
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
 mH83V9yQZ4TlJHtn2Baef   
    aruco
 mBduW7dqSuFrUAvwh7kHo   

 mTj14DRd7xgEPvsp5xhPs   





     CameraParameters mVlbuMLWi_vwpED0hDKIw      



 mrJuVHPe96ExiggCdsmDG   

   MarkerLabeler mv0LWHXRSvGJF76ckeLfO   



 mPXYuzTL9RZjjZA9XYUV9   
     MarkerDetector_Impl
 mYwjl00gOK3Vja3UkLMIP   


    friend  mukY8albO2VdJSsWPXwW4    

 MarkerDetector mD07x3flmZMPVC6kwqG6P    



public:

       MarkerDetector_Impl mnODdIJiXbJxgUNOnnK7Q     


   mYCDBBfn03HaGvoHBxAMq     


       MarkerDetector_Impl mK8B3zN6mQAB0xYXFlxGO     



    int dict_type,  mYJJZNT6RsQUQcGvcjw6s    

               error_correction_rate  mRUhvrauugCIk8ZFUtFF5      
           0 mswZzmsb_awITT3YY34kR
```

Comment: This looks like an [obfuscated code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_(software)) maybe in the hope of [minification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming))

Comment: Preprocessor macros.

Comment: "Open source is great because anyone can read the code and verify its correctness." ;-)

Comment: Just stay away from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What kind of code is in that file *.cpp.. #define mdTyVzgFy4_0UFy9GimmM

`#define mdTyVzgFy4_0UFy9GimmM` is a pre-processor directive that defines a macro. Macros are used to replace text during pre-processing.

> Would anyone understand what kind of code is that?

Probably no human can understand it. And that is probably the reason why that has been done in the first place: It seems to be an attempt to obfuscate the source code.

You can use a pre-processor to generate the processed code to see what the compiler sees. For example, `gcc -E`. Note that the pre-processor will expand the include directives, so you'll need to scroll past the included files first.

Answer (score 1):

> Would anyone understand what kind of code is that?

Yes! Wow this is fun. That is indeed an obfuscated source code. 
It is still C/C++. It is using pre-processor definitions. Basically it is a key that can be used multiple times. (like a variable).

The compiler will **search for all preprocessor definitions** and **replaces** them **by the actual text**.

I guess you want to deobfuscate it to have a closer look in the source code.

For `gcc` and `clang`, you can use the `-E` option (see similar answer) to output the preprocessor output without compiling.

To also show comments like in your sample output, you can add in the `-CC` and `-P` flags:

> clang++ -E -CC -P fileA.cpp
>
> All of the processor options for -E can be found on here, on
>   gcc.gnu.org.
>
> -CC Do not discard comments, including during macro expansion. This is like -C, except that comments contained within macros are also passed
>   through to the output file where the macro is expanded.
>
> -P Inhibit generation of linemarkers in the output from the preprocessor. This might be useful when running the preprocessor on
>   something that is not C code, and will be sent to a program which
>   might be confused by the linemarkers.

For the Visual C++ compiler, you can use `/E`.

Comment: I think that's a great answer. Looking at the preprocessed input will tell you what is going on in that file.